# How can I stop my script instead of progressing

Tags: perl

I did a simple script using perl and I was wondering how I can pause the program or return it  to the action before? I have this code

```
print "put your name:";
$s=<>;
```

and it didn't output anything. I want the program to repeat the same action, i.e. asking the user to enter his name instead of progressing.

Answer (score 3):

```
my $s = '';
while ($s eq '') {
    print "put your name:";
    chomp($s = <>);
}
    print "The name you entered is $s \n";
```

Comment: and what's the meaning of chomp function

Comment: [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) removes the return character from the end of a string.  Detailed specs available in the linked perldoc page.  If you're getting input from the console, you pretty much always want to chomp that data.  Could've done it on separate lines though: `$s = <>; chomp $s;`

Answer (score 2):

No need to set `$name` to anything before you start - just define it:

```
my $name;
while ( not length $name ) {  #Thx Dave Cross
    print "What is your name? ";
    $name = <STDIN>;
    chomp $name;
}
```

In Perl, variables defined with `my` (and that should be 99% of your variables) have a limited scope. If they're defined in a *block* (something that uses curly braces like this `while` loop), they'll lose their value once they leave the *block*. That's why I have to have `my $name;` before the `while`.

The `while ( not $name ) {` will work if `$name` isn't defined or is a null value, so this will loop until I enter something into `$name` that's not null.

The `chomp` removes the NL character that I enter when I press the `<ENTER>` key. You should always `chomp` your variables after a read of any sort. Just get use to it.

In this form, the loop is self documenting. I am looping while `$name` isn't filled in.

You can combine the `chomp` with the input like this:

```
my $name;
while ( not $name ) {
    print "What is your name? ";
    chomp ( $name = <STDIN> );
}
```

Some people like this because it's a bit shorter, but I don't know if its any clearer. I'm a fan of code clarity because it's easier to maintain.

Comment: thnx this one helps me :)

Comment: That won't accept a name of "0". Perhaps you want `while (not defined $name)` or `while (not length $name)`.

Comment: You're right. But, it will accept [0 but true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129945/what-does-0-but-true-mean-in-perl)! The `while ( not length $name )` is a good idea. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub readstr {
  while (my $in = <>) {
    chomp $in;
    return $in if length $in;
  }
  "";
}

print "put your name:";
my $s = readstr();
```